# Denormalize single cell RNAseq Data

Tags: python, r

Can anyone please help me this denormalization of the data.
I have the publicaly available normlaized count data which looks like this

V1       V2        V3 V4       V5        V6
0.13156778 0.000000 0.0000000  0 0.000000 0.0000000
0.00000000 0.192502 0.2321303  0 2.664751 0.3231619
0.06578389 0.000000 0.0000000  0 0.000000 0.0000000
0.00000000 0.385004 0.0000000  0 0.000000 0.0000000

this is how data has been normalized

#Each cell( i.e V1, V2 etc) has been normalized by dividing all counts by some factor (f).
#Thus the smallest nonzero value for each cell will be 1/f (where 1/f may differ across cells).
#So for each cell you can identify the factor and then recover the raw counts

can anyone please help me this, I am unable to get the raw counts

Comment: What kind of normalisation are you doing? TPM? RPKM? RPM?

Comment: its scRNA -seq Data which is already normalized by dividing all the counts in a cell by some factor. I want to convert this normlaized data to raw counts.

Answer (score 0):

You will have problems:

1. normalization goes along with information loss.
2. even if you are searching for smallest natural number (`1/f`), the floating point type will create problems (deviations from the true answer).

Comment: Hi Kim, thanks for telling me, but I still need an raw counts from from this normalized count data as I cant test the hypothesis we woking on. any help in denomalizing this count data would be really grateful. thanks